# class_getInstanceMethod is returing nil

Tags: swift

I was reading about method swizzle in swift. Trying to understand the class_getInstanceMethod method but its not working.

```
class Abc {

func testing() {
    print("testin...")
}

   func check() {
    print("check")
    let originalSelector = Selector.init(("testing"))
    let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(Abc.self , originalSelector)
    print("\(String(describing: originalMethod))")
  }
}  

 let a = Abc()
  a.check()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the `Selector`. Also must add `@objc` tag in `testing()`. This worked. I tested.

```
class Abc {

    @objc func testing() {
        print("testin...")
    }

    func check() {
        print("check")
        let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(Abc.self , #selector(self.testing))
        print("\(originalMethod))")
    }
}
```